# How do I fix this syntax error with print in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automl

I copied the Python code that Google Cloud recommends. I've tried it in `Jupyter Notebook` and as a Python file but I still get the **syntax error:**

```
def predict(content, project_id, model_id):
    # More code.
    pass

print predict("1.jpg", ispace-254720,  ICN886814670746214838)
```

Gives:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-a9c7141e2bf3>", line 1
    print predict("1.jpg", ispace-254720,  ICN886814670746214838)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I Haven't included the contents of the function

Answer (score 2):

It's probably old Python 2.7 code. I'm guessing you're using Python 3, in which case `print` is now a function, so you need to put parentheses after `print`:

```
print(predict("1.jpg", ispace-254720,  ICN886814670746214838))
```

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I missed that! Many Thanks